# How to make a textbox update brightness level?

Tags: awesome

I'm using Awesome window manager and have a textbox widget that I want to update with the current brightness level on an arbitrary interval of my choosing. Is there anyway to do this with Awesome and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question. It's mostly covered by using the information on the [widgets in awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Widgets_in_awesome) page. I havent set it up myself, but intend to use the same concepts for other functions. I'd use a combination of awful.widget.progressbar (brightness level is 0-100%). If you wanted to use your textbox, you can. add a signal to a timer widget that updates the text property of your textbox or use the set_value() if you want to use the Progressbar. Checkout the large list of [lua extensions that are packaged as libraries](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Main_Page#Lua_extensions). There may be one that already does what you want or something very similar.